# com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name) due to this not able to read the google spreadsheets

Tags: java, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I try to read the google docs from my JAVA code. I had given the correct credentials to access. But this was still showing as Authentication exception.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException
      {

          String status="";

            try{
                System.out.println("----");
                 SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");  System.out.println("Here  "+service);
                service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME,  GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
                System.out.println("Here 1");
                URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
                SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl,SpreadsheetEntry.class);
                URL listFeedUrl = spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0).getListFeedUrl();
            ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
            for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
                    System.out.println("new row");
                    for (String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags())
                    {
                        System.out.println("     " + tag + ": "
                                + entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
                        status=entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag);
           }
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println(status);
         }
```

> com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating
>   (check service name)

Comment: Which library are you using? It looks like you're using `ClientLogin` to authenticate, which was deprecated a long time ago.  You should be using OAuth 2.0 in order to authenticate. Start by reading [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). And check [this library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Is there any example code is there with you.Please share for us.
It will really helpful and appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ClientLogin` to authenticate, which was deprecated a long time ago. You should authenticate [via OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) instead.

You can find a clear, step by step guide to authenticate and make calls to Sheets API with Java [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). You would only need to modify the part related to the API call.

And [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) you can find code snippets in Java (and many other languages) for the different possible API calls in Sheets. Just look for the method you want to use in the left sidebar (`REST Resources`).

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)
- [Sheets API: Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)
- [Sheets API: Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

Comment: After I go through with the Google sheets API and their Java code
I got the below error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
 at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:41)
 at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory$InstanceHolder.

Comment: @NaveenKumar-nkp make sure that you import all the needed libraries to your script.